# Reseting values in React, socket.io real-time rock-paper-scissors game not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I've created a real-time rock-paper-scissors game and the problem is that whenever the first or second player resets the game and makes another choice after the first game it compares their choice with the previous choice from the other player.

```
 socket.on("choice", (data) => {
    console.log(`Player ${data.playerNumber} chose ${data.choice}`);

    // Find the other player
    const otherPlayer = players.find((player) => player !== socket.id);

    // Get the other player's choice
    socket.to(otherPlayer).emit("opposing-player-move", data.choice);
    socket.on("secondPlayerMove", (move) => {
      // Declare otherPlayerChoice here
      let otherPlayerChoice = move.choice;

      // Determine the winner
      let result;
      if (data.choice === otherPlayerChoice) {
        result = "It's a tie!";
      } else if (
        (data.choice === 0 && otherPlayerChoice === 2) ||
        (data.choice === 1 && otherPlayerChoice === 0) ||
        (data.choice === 2 && otherPlayerChoice === 1)
      ) {
        result = `Player ${data.playerNumber === 0 ? 1 : 0} wins!`;
      } else {
        result = `Player ${data.playerNumber} wins!`;
      }

      // Emit the result to both players
      io.to(socket.id).emit("game-result", result);
      io.to(otherPlayer).emit("game-result", result);
      io.emit("disable-buttons");

      // Reset otherPlayerChoice after the game ends
      otherPlayerChoice = null;
      data.choice = null;
    });
  });
```

this is what i've tried so far

I've tried various solutions but nothing works
Previous try:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

let players = [];
let otherPlayerChoice = null; // initialize otherPlayerChoice to null
let playerChoice = null; // initialize playerChoice to null

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  players.push(socket.id);

  const playerNumber = players.indexOf(socket.id);
  socket.emit("playerNumber", playerNumber);

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`User Disconnected: ${socket.id}`);

    const index = players.indexOf(socket.id);
    players.splice(index, 1);
  });

  socket.on("choice", (data) => {
    console.log(`Player ${data.playerNumber} chose ${data.choice}`);

    // Find the other player
    const otherPlayer = players.find((player) => player !== socket.id);

    // Get the other player's choice
    socket.to(otherPlayer).emit("opposing-player-move", data.choice);
    socket.on("test", (move) => {
      otherPlayerChoice = move.choice; // update otherPlayerChoice
      playerChoice = data.choice; // update playerChoice

      // Determine the winner
      let result;
      if (playerChoice === otherPlayerChoice) {
        result = "It's a tie!";
      } else if (
        (playerChoice === 0 && otherPlayerChoice === 2) ||
        (playerChoice === 1 && otherPlayerChoice === 0) ||
        (playerChoice === 2 && otherPlayerChoice === 1)
      ) {
        result = `Player ${data.playerNumber === 0 ? 1 : 0} wins!`;
      } else {
        result = `Player ${data.playerNumber} wins!`;
      }

      // Emit the result to both players
      io.to(socket.id).emit("game-result", result);
      io.to(otherPlayer).emit("game-result", result);
      io.emit("disable-buttons");

      // Reset the choices to null after the game ends
      otherPlayerChoice = null;
      playerChoice = null;
    });
  });
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING");
});
```

Comment: hello! just wondering if you find any solution? I'm currently also building real time RPS game too but I'm using firestore lol

Comment: Well @Amber , at the time that I was working on this project I didn't really know React that well. So I found a workaround. When the round was finished, the players would click the "Reset" button and the page would refresh. It's a bad fix, the players would have to join a room again and everytime they finished a round, they would have to do that again. But at that time I didn't know any better and finished the project as that. If you find a fix for this, be sure to respond to this thread because I'm very curious. Good luck!